# Einstein Chat Bot

Tags: einstein

[image]Im working on Einstein Chat Bot and in the initial greeting I wish to display logged in user name. Its displaying "Integration" . Any help how do I correct this?

Answer (score 6):

Use the cookbook that you'll find here: https://sfdc.co/BotsGuide
You'll need to gather the data from the prechat form, map it to the LiveChatTranscript and use the data in the FirstName slot to then create the greeting message. It's explained step by step in the document.

Answer (score 0):

You cant access to "logged user" info. Only can use Prechat Form

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/98740)

Comment: Say to someone that something is impossible... Is a solution

Answer (score 0):

The pre-chat form is rather limited when it comes to user information, Enrico Murru solved this issue with a lightning component: https://blog.enree.co/2018/11/salesforce-dealing-with-the-running-user-on-einstein-bot-dialogs.html

Comment: dead link, cannot open the mentioned link