# Retrieve user's name without Pre-chat form for Einstein Bots

Tags: apex, user, einstein, bots

I am creating an Einstein chatbot and I want to greet the user by their name. The Apex class that I have written for this purpose returns "Platform Integration User". An answer to another [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/222573/einstein-chat-bot) says to use a pre-chat form. Is there any way to get the logged-in user's details without having them fill a pre-chat form?

Comment: same doubt here, have already created this https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/235781/einstein-bot-get-current-user